# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice, valueerror

Why do the following code samples:

```
np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3, 4]])

np.array([1.2, "abc"], dtype=float)
```

all give the following error?

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: If you're like me and encountered this exception working with a Pandas Series, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044042/cant-convert-a-pandas-series-to-a-numpy-array-with-dtype-np-float64 may help.

Answer (score 379, accepted):

##### Possible reason 1: trying to create a jagged array

You may be creating an array from a list that isn't shaped like a multi-dimensional array:

```
numpy.array([[1, 2], [2, 3, 4]])         # wrong!
```

```
numpy.array([[1, 2], [2, [3, 4]]])       # wrong!
```

In these examples, the argument to `numpy.array` contains sequences of different lengths. Those will yield this error message because the input list is not shaped like a "box" that can be turned into a multidimensional array.

##### Possible reason 2: providing elements of incompatible types

For example, providing a string as an element in an array of type `float`:

```
numpy.array([1.2, "abc"], dtype=float)   # wrong!
```

If you really want to have a NumPy array containing both strings and floats, you could use the dtype `object`, which allows the array to hold arbitrary Python objects:

```
numpy.array([1.2, "abc"], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 92):

**The Python ValueError:**

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Means exactly what it says, you're trying to cram a sequence of numbers into a single number slot.  It can be thrown under various circumstances.

**1.  When you pass a python tuple or list to be interpreted as a numpy array element:**

```
import numpy

numpy.array([1,2,3])               #good

numpy.array([1, (2,3)])            #Fail, can't convert a tuple into a numpy 
                                   #array element


numpy.mean([5,(6+7)])              #good

numpy.mean([5,tuple(range(2))])    #Fail, can't convert a tuple into a numpy 
                                   #array element


def foo():
    return 3
numpy.array([2, foo()])            #good


def foo():
    return [3,4]
numpy.array([2, foo()])            #Fail, can't convert a list into a numpy 
                                   #array element
```

**2.  By trying to cram a numpy array length > 1 into a numpy array element:**

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
x[0] = np.array([4])         #good



x = np.array([1,2,3])
x[0] = np.array([4,5])       #Fail, can't convert the numpy array to fit 
                             #into a numpy array element
```

A numpy array is being created, and numpy doesn't know how to cram multivalued tuples or arrays into single element slots.  It expects whatever you give it to evaluate to a single number, if it doesn't, Numpy responds that it doesn't know how to set an array element with a sequence.

Answer (score 26):

In my case , I got this Error in Tensorflow , Reason was i was trying to feed a array with different length or sequences :

example :

```
import tensorflow as tf

input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None,None])



word_embedding = tf.get_variable('embeddin',shape=[len(vocab_),110],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01,0.01))

embedding_look=tf.nn.embedding_lookup(word_embedding,input_x)

with tf.Session() as tt:
    tt.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    a,b=tt.run([word_embedding,embedding_look],feed_dict={input_x:example_array})
    print(b)
```

And if my array is :

```
example_array = [[1,2,3],[1,2]]
```

Then i will get error :

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

but if i do padding then :

```
example_array = [[1,2,3],[1,2,0]]
```

Now it's working.

Answer (score 17):

for those who are having trouble with similar problems in Numpy, a very simple solution would be:

defining `dtype=object` when defining an array for assigning values to it. for instance:

```
out = np.empty_like(lil_img, dtype=object)
```

Comment: How is it different from `Edit` part of accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the problem was another. I was trying convert lists of lists of int to array. The problem was that there was one list with a different length than others. If you want to prove it, you must do:

```
print([i for i,x in enumerate(list) if len(x) != 560])
```

In my case, the length reference was 560.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was with a scatterplot of a dataframe X[]:

```
ax.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],c=colors,    
       cmap=CMAP, edgecolor='k', s=40)  #c=y[:,0],

#ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
#Fix with .toarray():
colors = 'br'
y = label_binarize(y, classes=['Irrelevant','Relevant'])
ax.scatter(X[:,0].toarray(),X[:,1].toarray(),c=colors,   
       cmap=CMAP, edgecolor='k', s=40)
```

Comment: The value error means we're trying to load a n-element array (sequence) into a single number slot which only has a float. Hence, you're trying to set an array element  with a sequence. With .toarray() we enlarge it to an array of sequence.
toarray() returns an ndarray;

Answer (score 3):

A common reason this error occurs is when you want to change the dtype of an array from `object` to `int`/`float` etc using an `astype()` call. There could be two cases:

- ###### a) jagged array

  The most common case is when the array is jagged. In this case, the "inner" array probably needs to be flattened before changing the dtype.

  ```py
  import numpy as np
  arr = np.array([1,2, [3,4]], dtype=object)
  arr.astype(int)             # <--- ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

  # flatten array
  out = []
  for x in arr:
      if isinstance(x, (list, np.ndarray, tuple)):
          out.extend(x)
      else:
          out.append(x)
  arr = np.array(out)         # <--- OK
  ```

  ###### b) "inner" arrays are not read properly

  Another common case is when an `object` dtype array's "inner" arrays are not read properly, which causes this error even if the shapes and dtypes are seemingly a-OK.

  For example in the following case, the "inner" arrays of `arr` have the same shape (and have the same dtype as well), so we don't have the jagged array problem, yet when calling `astype(int)`, we get the error in the title.

  ```py
  arr = np.array([1, 2], dtype=object)
  arr[:2] = [[10], [20]]
  arr                     # array([list([10]), list([20])], dtype=object)

  arr.astype(int)         # <--- ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
  ```

  In this case, convert `arr` into a list and convert to an ndarray later; or just `stack()` it.

  ```py
  np.array(arr.tolist())  # <--- OK
  np.stack(arr)           # <--- OK
  ```

  This error commonly occurs when a pandas column that contained lists/ndarrays are attempted to be converted into a numpy ndarray using `astype()`. In other words, it occurs if you want to make the following conversion using `astype()`.

  [image: pandas-case]

  In this case, instead of `astype()`, use `stack()` or convert to a list and cast to an ndarray.

  ```
  import pandas as pd

  s = pd.Series([[1,2], [3,4]])

  s.astype(int)             # <--- ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
  s.to_numpy().astype(int)  # <--- ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
  np.array(s.tolist())      # <--- OK
  np.stack(s)               # <--- OK
  ```

###### `np.where()`/`np.nonzero()` returns a tuple

Another common example where this error occurs is when you want to assign the values returned from `np.where()` to an array. However, `np.where()` when only the condition is passed returns a tuple (same with `np.nonzero()`), which leads to this error, for the same reason explained in [Eric Leschinski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47482672/19123103). In this case, assign only the relevant value from the tuple (in the example below, that is the first item in the tuple).

```py
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])

arr[:3] = np.where(arr>0)       # <--- ValueError: ...
arr[:3] = np.where(arr>0)[0]    # <--- OK
arr[:3] = np.nonzero(arr>0)[0]  # <--- OK
```

Comment: I encounter this error when using pandas, and your example clearly explain how to solve it in this case!

Answer (score 2):

When the shape is not regular or the elements have different data types, the `dtype` argument passed to np.array only can be `object`.

```py
import numpy as np

# arr1 = np.array([[10, 20.], [30], [40]], dtype=np.float32)  # error
arr2 = np.array([[10, 20.], [30], [40]])  # OK, and the dtype is object
arr3 = np.array([[10, 20.], 'hello'])     # OK, and the dtype is also object
```

``

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is very old, and it looks like your answer duplicates at least one of the others. If your answer is in fact different, try adding some more detail that explains how.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had a nested list as the series that I wanted to use as an input.

First check: If

```
df['nestedList'][0]
```

outputs a list like `[1,2,3]`, you have a nested list.

Then check if you still get the error when changing to input `df['nestedList'][0]`.

Then your next step is probably to concatenate all nested lists into one unnested list, using

```
[item for sublist in df['nestedList'] for item in sublist]
```

This flattening of the nested list is borrowed from [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists).

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the dtype argument of the np.array function specifies the data type of the elements in the array, and it can only be set to a single data type that is compatible with all the elements. The value "abc" is not a valid float, so trying to convert it to a float results in a ValueError. To avoid this error, you can either remove the string element from the list, or choose a different data type that can handle both float values and string values, such as object.

```
numpy.array([1.2, "abc"], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a version problem. I got the error for numpy version = 1.24.1. But when I downgraded to 1.21.6, the problem was fixed.

```
python -m pip install numpy==1.21.6
```