# Theano function raises ValueError with 'givens' attribute

Tags: python, theano

I use `theano` function and want to use `givens` to iterate all the input samples. The code is as below:

```
index = T.scalar('index')
train_set = np.array([[0.2, 0.5, 0.01], [0.3, 0.91, 0.4], [0.1, 0.7, 0.22], 
                      [0.7, 0.54, 0.2], [0.1, 0.12, 0.3], [0.2, 0.52, 0.1], 
                      [0.12, 0.08, 0.4], [0.02, 0.7, 0.22], [0.71, 0.5, 0.2], 
                      [0.1, 0.42, 0.63]])
train = function(inputs=[index], outputs=cost, updates=updates, 
                 givens={x: train_set[index]})
```

It eventually raises an error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Could you tell me why, and how to solve the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence)

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate of the question that you provide

Comment: The error is a general one, and the cause is mentioned in the answer of the qeustion I linked.

Comment: I can't get any idea to solve it by what you linked. My train_set is a numpy ndarray whose shape is (10,3) and all items is float. It seems that it doesn't accord with all the probably problem in the question what you linked.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this: `train_set[index]`

Here train_set is a numpy ndarray and index a Theano variable. NumPy don't know how to work with Theano variables. You must convert train_set to a Theano variable like a shared variable:

```
train_set = theano.shared(train_set)
```

You also need to change your declaration of index as Theano don't support real value for index:

```
index = T.iscalar()
```