# Converting list to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I have managed to load images in a folder using the command line sklearn: `load_sample_images()`

I would now like to convert it to a `numpy.ndarray` format with `float32` datatype

I was able to convert it to `np.ndarray` using : `np.array(X)`, however `np.array(X, dtype=np.float32)` and `np.asarray(X).astype('float32')` give me the error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Is there a way to work around this?

```py
from sklearn_theano.datasets import load_sample_images
import numpy as np  

kinect_images = load_sample_images()
X = kinect_images.images

X_new = np.array(X)  # works
X_new = np.array(X[1], dtype=np.float32)  # works

X_new = np.array(X, dtype=np.float32)  # does not work
```

Comment: You have a list of lists, where not all lists have the same amount of entries.

Comment: ok. What is the solution? New to python so please bear with me

Comment: Check the type after your `np.array(x)` is successful. If it is float64 which is the default - then you are simply trying to assign a type which is not suitable for your list (or list of lists).

Comment: possible duplicate of [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence)

Comment: The dtype of np.array(x) uint8. I think it is a list of lists

Comment: if it's really uint8, then there should be no problem to convert it into float32. But I doubt this. Can you show more code?

Comment: Also np.array(X[1], dtype=np.float32) works...

Comment: it seems unlikely that  ``np.array(X).dtype == np.uint8`` but ``np.array(X, dtype=np.float32)`` fails. To check if all lists that you want to put in the array have the same length, you can do ``np.unique([len(x) for x in X])``

Comment: Thanks the images were of different sizes

Answer (score 149):

If you have a list of lists, you only needed to use ...

```
import numpy as np
...
npa = np.asarray(someListOfLists, dtype=np.float32)
```

per this [**LINK**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) in the scipy / numpy documentation. You just needed to define dtype inside the call to asarray.

Answer (score 3):

If you're converting a list into an array, you'll need to make a new copy anyway, so

```py
arr = np.array(my_list, dtype='float32')
```

also works.

One use case is when `my_list` is not actually a list but some other list-like object; in which case explicitly casting to list beforehand might be helpful.

```py
arr = np.array(list(my_list), dtype='float32')
```

For example,

```py
my_list = pd.Series([[1], [2], [3]]).values

np.array(my_list)             # jagged array; not OK
np.array(list(my_list))       # OK
np.array(my_list.tolist())    # OK


my_list = {'a': [1], 'b': [2]}.values()
np.array(my_list)             # jagged array; not OK
np.array(list(my_list))       # OK
```

To cast nested list into an array, the shapes of the sublists must match. If they don't maybe you want to concatenate the sublists along some axis. Try `np.concatenate`/`np.r_`/`np.c_` etc. instead.