# How do I convert this list to a np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a script where I need to convert a list to a numpy array, but I'm having this weird problem and I don't know how to solve it.

```
>>> a = [6.27575197488659, 28.91240527183621, -0.005173032150138807]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(a)
array([ 6.27575197e+00,  2.89124053e+01, -5.17303215e-03])
```

The array should be the same as the list and you would safe my day by helping me.

Comment: What is the weird problem? The values are the same; `e-03` means `10^(-3) `.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same! You can verify it simply by

```py
list(np.array(a))
```

Only numpy represents the floats in the scientific (exp) format, that's all!

Answer (score -1):

Update for 2023!!

Use

```py
np.array(a,dtype='object')
```

Currently, it is showing VisibleDeprecationWarning, to avoid it, use `dtype='object'` while converting.

The question is duplicate of this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75551268/20238141)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, do not do this! You defeat the purpose of using numpy by setting `dtype=object`.

Comment: Also if you think a question is a duplicate, flag/vote to close it as such once you've earned that [privilege](/help/privileges)