# Numpy linspace and plotting, ValueError: an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to get 60 lines joining center of the circle to 60 different equispaced points on the circumference in the following program,

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

figure = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 60)
r = 3.0
x1 = r * np.cos(theta)
y1 = r * np.sin(theta)

plt.plot(x1, y1, color='blue')
plt.plot([0, x1], [0, y1], color='gray')

plt.axis([-4, 4, -4, 4])
plt.grid(True)

figure.tight_layout()
figure.savefig('test.png', facecolor='white', edgecolor='black')
```

It gives the following error,

```python
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    plt.plot([0, x1], [0, y1], color='gray')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2987, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4137, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 317, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 288, in _plot_args
    y = np.atleast_1d(tup[-1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 49, in atleast_1d
    ary = asanyarray(ary)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 512, in asanyarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

If I use some constant value for example `plt.plot([0, 0], [0, r], color='gray')` instead of `plt.plot([0, x1], [0, y1], color='gray')` it works. It seems with `numpy.linspace` such plot is not possible.

I found similar question [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4674473/2026294), but did not help me. I am new to python, please bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x and y elements of your `plot()` command need to have the same number of elements. Replace the line

```
plt.plot([0, x1], [0, y1], color='gray')
```

with the following:

```
plt.plot([np.zeros(60,), x1], [np.zeros(60,), y1], color='gray')
```

the result looks like:
[image]