# How to convert a Python list of lists to a 2D numpy array for sklearn.preprocessing

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, scikit-learn

I currently have a list which contains all of my input for an sklearn classifier. Each element in that list is a list of features, where each element represents a song in my dataset.

I need to convert this structure to a 2D numpy array so I can scale my data via sklearn's preprocessing. This is proving to be very difficult.

`y = []
all_feats = []
for song in data:
    mfccs_in_song = song[0]
     oned_mfccs_in_song = []
     for frame in mfccs_in_song:
        for m in frame:
            oned_mfccs_in_song.append(m)
     all_feats.append(oned_mfccs_in_song)
     label = song[-1]
     y.append(label)`

Long story short, all_feats is that list of lists. It has a length of 600. How can I convert this to a numpy array for preprocessing? I have tried numerous things, including simply `all_feats = np.array(all_feats)`, however that does not work.

Comment: What is the issue with using `all_feats = np.array(all_feats)`? Does it give an error? What error?

Comment: File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 129, in scale
    dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 382, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Take a look at the suggestions/answers given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence). More specifically, look at the resulting `all_feats`. It may not have sublists of the same size.

Comment: You were right. There was one sublist out of the 600 that wasn't the same size!

Comment: Great, I'll add my suggestion as an answer and you can accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error suggests that `all_feats` may not have sublists of the same size. Take a look at its contents, and once you figure out what's the right length for the sublists, and how to prune the extra elements out, you can run `all_feats = np.array(all_feats)` and it should work!

Take a look at the answers in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence) for more explanation.

Comment: Yep, fixed it. Simply found the minimum length of all the sublists and resized the bad apple! Python slicing to the rescue.