# What kind of tensorflow placeholder shape to use to contain such sequence?

Tags: tensorflow

This is the sequence I intend to input:

```
sequence = [[[113, 162, 159], [3, 163, 417], [393, 77, 333], [420, 214, 382], [308, 441, 175], [152, 80, 477], [184, 101, 54], [417, 277, 487], [494, 329, 315], [413, 386, 319]], 
[425, 132, 407], 
[405]]
```

However, I am unable to determine what shape of placeholder to use for it.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, 3], name='probable_solutions')
sess = tf.Session()
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_op)
sess.run(x, feed_dict={x: [sequence[0], sequence[1], sequence[2]]})
```

This gives me the following error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Here's the full code-
https://pastebin.com/cq44wcir

(I've also marked a few questions in the pastebin code - you can find them by searching for '#~~#', no quotes, in the text)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? 
What do these numbers mean?

Comment: These are indexes of words.

The output will be similar to the first array of the sequence.

Comment: Could you explain , why do you expect such output

Comment: It's a graph traversal. [[Node_1, Edge_Property, Node_2], [Node_2, E_P, etc.

Comment: Can you add whole code here? or on pastebin

Comment: Unfortunately, this is all I have. Also, I am new to machine learning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157787/discussion-between-arseniy-and-ishaan-patel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Collected from :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence)

first of all before sending it to feed_dict, `sequence` should be a numpy array.

of course, you can convert it to numpy array easily but that's not the solution.

It's clear that you are trying to create an array from a list which isn't shaped like a multi-dimensional array.

Any array which isn't "Generalized" cannot be used as feed_dict