# What is the exact meaning of multi-dimensional array for numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

Can someone tell me why `a` works while `b` does not with `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence) says the "multi-dimensional" reason, but in my case, I think `a` and `b` are the same.

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[1],2,3])
b=np.array([1,2,[3]])
```

Comment: Making an array from lists with mixed nesting is tricky.  `np.array` first tries to make a regular multidimensional array.   It fails for both `a` and `b`, so has to fall back on ad hoc alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy is observing the first element to see what dtype the array is going to have.  For `a` it sees a list and therefore produces an `object` array.  It happily moves on to fill in the rest of the elements into the `object` array.  For `b`, it sees a numeric value and assumes it's going to be some numeric `dtype`.  Then it borks when it gets to a list.

You can override this by stating `object` dtype in the first place

```
a=np.array([[1],2,3])
b=np.array([1,2,[3]], 'object')

print(a, b, sep='\n\n')

[list([1]) 2 3]

[1 2 list([3])]
```

Mind you, that may not be exactly how Numpy is identifying `dtype` but it's got to be pretty close.

Comment: So `list([1])` means it is only a `list`, not a `numpy list`?

Comment: _For a it sees a list and therefore produces an object array._ It really can't be that simple since for example `[[1], [2], [3]]` looks exactly the same in the first position.

Comment: @PaulPanzer you are right of course.  But it's the simplest way to get the point across. Numpy is doing some checking.  Those checks fail to make the correct guess for `b = np.array([1, 2, [3]])`