# Python: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, valueerror

I'm trying to use **scikit-learn** to do some ML.

I am using the **preprocessing** module to prep my data. The data are of type **float**.

From reading other questions regarding this issue: [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence), it's either due to wrong structure of my data or because my data is of type string. Neither seem to be the case here.

Please let me know if you have any idea how to solve this issue or what it even means. Thank you.

The code:

```
print(X)

pred_X = np.array(pred_X)
pred_Y = np.array(pred_Y)
X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)

X = preprocessing.scale(X)
pred_X = preprocessing.scale(pred_X)
```

print(x):

```
[[547180.0, 120.0, 113.0, 456701.0, 1.0, 6.43, -1.0, 0.313, 0.42, 0.267 3.0, 11800.0, 607208.0, 120.0, 113.0, 456701.0, 1.0, 0.273, 0.331, 0.154, 6.0, 10300.0, 458015.0, 113.0, 120.0, 45328 6.0, 1.0, 2.54, -1.0, 0.32, 0.443, 0.257, 3.0, 92000.0, 543685.0, 120.0, 113.0, 456701.0, 1.0, 6.43, 1.0, 0.296, 0.4, 0.234, 2.0, 8800.0, 594809.0, 475582.0, 120.0, 113.0, 456701.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.295, 0.384, 0.264, 4.0, 7700.0], 
[547180.0, 120.0, 113.0, 456701.0, 1.0, 6.43, -1.0, 0.313, 0.42, 0.267, 3.0, 11800.0, 607208.0, 120.0, 113.0, 456701.0, 1.0, 0.273, 0.331, 0.154, 6.0, 10300.0, 458015.0, 113.0, 120.0, 453286.0, 1.0, 2.54, -1.0, 0.32, 0.443, 0.257, 3.0, 92000.0, 543685.0, 120.0, 113.0, 456701.0, 1.0, 6.43, 1.0, 0.296, 0.4, 0.234, 2.0, 8800.0, 594809.0, 435062.0, 120.0, 113.0, 456701.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.312, 0.364, 0.154, 5.0, 6900.0], 
[547180.0, 120.0, 113.0, 456701.0, 1.0, 6.43, -1.0, 0.313, 0.42, 0.267, 3.0, 11800.0, 607208.0, 120.0, 113.0, 456701.0, 1.0, 0.273, 0.331, 0.154, 6.0, 10300.0, 458015.0, 113.0, 120.0, 453286.0, 1.0, 2.54, -1.0, 0.32, 0.443, 0.257, 3.0, 92000.0, 543685.0, 120.0, 113.0, 456701.0, 1.0, 6.43, 1.0, 0.296, 0.4, 0.234, 2.0, 8800.0, 594809.0, 446308.0, 120.0, 113.0, 456701.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.221, 0.28e, 0.115, 8.0, 6400.0]]
```

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleSVM.py", line 46, in <module>
    X = preprocessing.scale(X)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py", line 133, in scale
    dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Elements like `45328 6.0` prevent me from copy-n-pasting your `X`.

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 14):

Your input array X is malformed. There are 59 elements in row 1, and 58 in rows 2 & 3. When you convert to a `numpy` array it becomes an array of shape `(3,)` with `dtype=Object`.

The solution is to check and fix your input data. Each row in X must be the same length.