# Custom preprocessing_function with tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale - ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-preprocessing

I am trying to use a custom preprocessing function to convert RGB images to grayscale during training. As such, I try to use `tf.image.rbg_to_grayscale` for this. My function looks as following:

```
def prep_data(x):
    x = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(x)
    return x

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=prep_data,validation_split=0.15)
```

The `train_generator` is defined using `datagen.flow_from_dataframe(...)`. Training without this custom function works just fine, however once I use it I get the following error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Judging from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence), I assume I need to change my input to `rgb_to_grayscale`, but I don't know what's the correct way of passing `x` to the function.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you can use the `color_mode` argument of `flow_from_directory` and set it to `'grayscale'` to convert the images to grayscale. From [Keras docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory):

> **color_mode**: One of "grayscale", "rbg", "rgba". Default: "rgb". Whether the images will be converted to have 1, 3, or 4 channels.

Answer (score 0):

change RGB image to greyscale (example):

```
img = image.load_img('/kaggle/input/cassava-leaf-disease-classification/train_images/'+train['image_id'][i], target_size=(28,28,1), color_mode="grayscale")
```