# Having trouble summing along the third axis in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, rgb, numpy-ndarray

I am working on a program that takes a screenshot and saves the pixels in a Numpy Array with 3 axis (X, Y, and the RGB value itself) and cannot properly sum the last axis.

I have searched up information on this topic, and although I have tried several things such as "Axis=2" I have made no progress. I would like to stay away from for loops. Because although they work I feel as though that defeats the purpose of sum in the first place.

```
#Imports
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab

#Define Hight and Width of screen
height = 1080
width = 1920


#Capture screen with by taking individual RGB values in an array
screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,width,height)))

red = np.sum(screen[[0][0]])
green = np.sum(screen[[1][0]])
blue = np.sum(screen[[2][0]])

print(red,blue,green)
```

I am hoping to get the result that the variables red green and blue show their respective value of the sum of all of the pixels on the screen, however I am currently getting "1468800" for all of them. Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, simply setting `axis=2` should work. Here is a working example:

```
# sample RGB image to work with
In [24]: from skimage import data
In [25]: astronaut = data.astronaut()
In [26]: astronaut.shape
Out[26]: (512, 512, 3)

# sum the RGB values (R+G+B)
In [30]: astronaut_summed = np.sum(astronaut, axis=2)
In [31]: astronaut_summed.shape
Out[31]: (512, 512)
```

---

P.S. Since I'm on *nix, I cannot check the working of `PIL.ImageGrab` because that works only on MacOS and Windows.

Comment: I tried this out and am unsure as to what problem I'm facing, as it seems that it should work. this is the new code
```
while(True):
    #Capture screen with by taking individual RGB values in an array
    screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,width,height)))

    red = np.sum(screen, axis=2)
    green = np.sum(screen[[1][0]])
    blue = np.sum(screen[[2][0]])
```
and im getting this error "  File "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

Comment: @Grimm_boss so the problem is that you should not assign to any of `red`, `green`, or `blue`. see this thread for more info: [valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47482672)