# How to resolve, ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

This is my code, getting error even when I did `one-hot encoding`, but that doesn't worked for me.Than I converted sequence to number by self But while compiling  error occurs "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"

Please guide me how to fit data into Neural Netwrok, I have list of protein sequences in one column of csv file, and and in 2nd column their structures named `a, ab, b`

```
df= pd.read_csv('/home/alpha/mk fyp/whole/DATASET2.csv',names=('X1','Y'),delimiter=',')
X1=df.iloc[:,0].values
Y=df.iloc[:,1:2].values
def convert(sequence):
for item in sequence:
    try:
        yield float(item)
    except ValueError as e:
        yield item

a = [[item for item in convert(sublist)] for sublist in X1]
X = np.array(a)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.20)
# define a simple CNN model
def baseline_model():
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(input_dim = 1, units = 10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='uniform'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model 
# build the model
model = baseline_model()
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, validation_data=(X1, Y), epochs=10, batch_size=200)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("CNN Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence)

Comment: This is not reproducible without the full Traceback and test data.

Comment: I already mentioned ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence?
is the problem while fitting data into neural model.