# ODES: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations, valueerror

I am trying to define the following system of ODES in python:
[image: the following system of ODES in python]

### this way:

```
def rhs(t, P):
    dP = np.zeros_like(P)
    dP[0] = np.sqrt((1 - 3 / P) * (2 + 4 / P**2))
    dP[1] = 1 / math.pow(P,2)
    return dP
```

However, I am getting an error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I am not sure what is the problem... Would be grateful for any help with this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, your state P has 2 components. Thus also the expressions you compute from P will have two components. Then you try to assign these tuples to a single cell in the array `dP`, which is not possible and results in that error message.

You might want to replace `P` with its first element `P[0]` in these expressions. Or use

```
def rhs(t, u):
    P,phi = u
    dP = ...
    dphi = ...
    return [dP, dphi]
```