# can't convert a pandas.Series to a numpy.array with dtype=np.float64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have to convert a pandas Series to NumPy array of dtype=float64, this is the code that raises the error:

```
series = pd.Series( [np.random.randn(5), np.random.randn(5), np.random.randn(5), np.random.randn(5)])

res = series.to_numpy()
res.astype(np.float64)
```

This is the error I got:

```
----> 3 res.astype(np.float64)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I want to understand why this raises an error and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Just curious why you're putting the arrays in a Series in the first place, only to go back to arrays?

Comment: I have a complex data pipeline, that requires this kind of behaviour, the code there is just to makes it easier for members to reproduce the error.

Comment: Ok, fair point.  Just popped an alternative solution on for you ... see if that might be an option for you.

Comment: thanks a lot, it wouldn't work for me this time, but I am sure it'll come in handy another day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a series of list, which cannot be converted to a single float. Try:

```
res = np.array(series.to_list(), dtype=np.float64)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, can you please elaborate on why my approach didn't work?

Comment: I already explained in my answer. A little more details: `res = series.to_numpy()` is a numpy 1D array of objects, each is a list and cannot converted to float.

Answer (score 1):

Would using pure `numpy` be an option for you, and leave `pandas.Series` out of the mix? The end result of this, and converting the arrays -> Series -> arrays, are the same.

Example:

```
np.hstack([np.random.randn(5), 
           np.random.randn(5), 
           np.random.randn(5), 
           np.random.randn(5)]).reshape(4, -1)
```

Output:

```
array([[-1.04567727,  1.10871164, -0.00289682, -1.46394996, -1.6533185 ],
       [-0.27568511, -1.14668944, -0.86748842,  1.49770095,  1.73787835],
       [-0.92369818,  0.10933332, -0.14575781, -0.74659525, -0.84642341],
       [ 0.43899992,  0.93004048, -1.11173766,  0.25189761, -0.66619674]])
```