# I'm getting an error when trying to fit a sklearn model. TypeError: Only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = []
y = []

classes = [r"Anthracnose", r"Leaf Crinkcle", r"Powdery Mildew", r"Yellow Mosaic", r"Healthy"]

for i in range(5):
    for filename in glob.glob(r"C:\-\-\-\-\-\-\\" + classes[i] + r"/*.jpg"):
        image = Image.open(filename)
        matrix_temp = np.array(image)
        X.append(matrix_temp)
        y.append(i)

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2)


X_train = np.array(X_train, dtype=object).reshape(-1,1)
y_train = np.array(y_train).reshape(-1,1)
X_test = np.array(X_test, dtype=object).reshape(-1,1)
y_test = np.array(y_test).reshape(-1,1)


model = MLPClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\path_to_file\plants.py", line 32, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\path_to_file\_multilayer_perceptron.py", line 762, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, incremental=False)
  File "C:\path_to_file\_multilayer_perceptron.py", line 394, in _fit
    X, y = self._validate_input(X, y, incremental, reset=first_pass)
  File "C:\path_to_file\_multilayer_perceptron.py", line 1109, in _validate_input
    X, y = self._validate_data(
  File "C:\path_to_file\base.py", line 596, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "C:\path_to_file\validation.py", line 1074, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(
  File "C:\path_to_file\validation.py", line 856, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I'm confused on what this error can mean and don't know what to try. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Hi, please share the whole error code so that it will be easier for us to check where does the error originate from.

Comment: Done Joshua. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Tell us about `X_train, y_train` - shape and dtype

Comment: @hpaulj I believe X_train is a 2D numpy array of numpy matrices. Y_train is a 2D numpy array of integers

Comment: Does that mean object dtype?  `fit` is probably trying `np.array(X_train, dtype=float)`

Comment: @hpaulj But I specify dtype=object when converting to a np array

Comment: @Bob123 reading your error code, it seems X_train having issue, maybe you try and see does this help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence

Comment: But `fit` needs a float array.  If you have to specify object, then your component arrays don't match in shape.

Comment: @hpaulj Oh I see what you are saying. How can I convert to a float array? Since I am using the numpy.array function on the image, the X_train array contains a 2D numpy matrix for each image.

Comment: Have you resized all the images to the same shape?  Are they all same color v. b/w?

Comment: I guess that the problem is the shape of X. It seems that X is 2D (images, right?). But the MLPClassifier expects for each sample a 1D Vector. That is why you need to `flatten` your data first from 2D into 1D. For example, you could use numpy's flatten function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is the shape of `X_train`. `X` before transforming it is of size: (*number_of_samples, height, width*). The `MLPClassifier's` [fit function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.fit) expects the following shape: (*number_of_samples, number_of_features*). Thus, you need to reshape your 2D images into 1D vectors (features) by, for example, concatenating the rows, such that the input `X` is: (*number_of_samples, height x width*).

However, in your example you transform `X_train` using `reshape(-1, 1)` which leads to the following shape: (*number_of_samples x height x width*)

Illustrative example: Let's say you have 2 images of size 3x3 each. The goal is to transform them such that each 'image' is of size 1x9 instead of size 3x3. For example, you can use numpy's [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((2, 3, 3))  # Shape is (2,3,3). It's like 2 images with size 3x3 each
a_reshaped = a.reshape((2, 9)). # Reshape the two images
print(a_reshaped)
a_reshaped_2 = a.reshape((2, -1)). # Same result as above
print(a_reshaped_2)
a_reshaped_wrong = a.reshape(-1, 1). # What you do
print(a_reshaped_wrong.shape())  # Check the size and see what's different
```

Finally, note that each image must have the same size. Working with different heights and widths does also lead to an error.

I hope that helps.