# ddeint - problem with reproducing examples provided in pypi

Tags: python, valueerror

I wanted to use the ddeint in my project. I copied the two examples provided on
https://pypi.org/project/ddeint/
and only the second one works. When I'm running the first one:

```py
from pylab import cos, linspace, subplots
from ddeint import ddeint


def model(Y, t):
    return -Y(t - 3 * cos(Y(t)) ** 2)


def values_before_zero(t):
    return 1


tt = linspace(0, 30, 2000)
yy = ddeint(model, values_before_zero, tt)

fig, ax = subplots(1, figsize=(4, 4))
ax.plot(tt, yy)
ax.figure.savefig("variable_delay.jpeg")
```

The following error occures:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\piobo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    yy = ddeint(model, values_before_zero, tt)
  File "C:\Users\piobo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\ddeint\ddeint.py", line 145, in ddeint
    return np.array([g(tt[0])] + results)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2000,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

I'm using python 3.9. Could anyone advise us on what I'm doing wrong? I didn't manipulate the code in any way.

Comment: Please share the code that you executed as [example] here and paste the full error-output (including stack traceback) - [edit]. This [`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` might be related to numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence).

Comment: I have provided the code and full error now

Comment: Thanks. One more question: What is your numpy version? (Can use `pip3 show numpy` to show it).

Comment: I use version 1.24.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reproduction

Could not reproduce - the code runs when using following versions:

- Python 3.6.9 (`python3 --version`)
- ddeint 0.2 (`pip3 show ddeint`)
- Numpy 1.18.3 (`pip3 show numpy`)

#### Upgrading numpy to 1.19

Then I got following warning:

> /.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ddeint/ddeint.py:145: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
> return np.array([g(tt[0])] + results)

But the output JPEG was created successfully.

#### Using Python 3.8 with latest numpy

Using Python 3.8 with a fresh install of ddeint using numpy 1.24.0:

- Python 3.8
- ddeint 0.2
- Numpy 1.24.0

Now I could reproduce the error.

#### Hypotheses

Since this example does not run successfully out-of-the-box in the question's environment, I assume it is an issue with numpy versions.

#### Issue with versions

See [Numpy 1.19 deprecation warning · Issue #9 · Zulko/ddeint · GitHub](https://github.com/Zulko/ddeint/issues/9) which seems related to this code line that we see in the error stacktrace:

```
    return np.array([g(tt[0])] + results)
```

#### Directly using `numpy`

I suppose the `tt` value is the issue here. It is returned by `pylab`'s `linspace()` function call (below written with module prefix):

```
tt = pylab.linspace(0, 30, 2000)
```

On MatPlotLib's [`pylab` docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/index#module-pylab) there is a warning:

> Since heavily importing into the global namespace may result in unexpected behavior, the use of pylab is strongly discouraged. Use matplotlib.pyplot instead.

Furthermore the module `pylab` is explained as mixed bag:

> pylab is a module that includes matplotlib.pyplot, numpy, numpy.fft, numpy.linalg, numpy.random, and some additional functions, all within a single namespace. Its original purpose was to mimic a MATLAB-like way of working by importing all functions into the global namespace. This is considered bad style nowadays.

Maybe you can use [`numpy.linspace()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) function directly.

Attention: There was a change for the `dtype` default:

> The type of the output array. If `dtype` is not given, the data type is inferred from `start` and `stop`. The inferred `dtype` **will never be an integer**; float is chosen even if the arguments would produce an array of integers.

Since here arguments `start` and `stop` are given as `0` and `30`, also the `dtype` should be integer (like in previous [numpy version 1.19](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)).

Note the braking-change:

> Since 1.20.0
>
> Values are rounded towards `-inf` instead of `0` when an integer `dtype` is specified. The old behavior can still be obtained with `np.linspace(start, stop, num).astype(int)`

So, we could replace the tt-assignment line with:

```
from numpy import np

tt = np.linspace(0, 30, 2000).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm on version 3.9.13 of python and 1.24.0 of numpy. Unfortunetely the replacement of the tt assignement with the line you have provided didn't fix the issue

Comment: Update: I changed to Python 3.8 and diwngraded numpy to 1.19 - I got the same result as you. I'll stick with it for now. Thank you for your help!