# Image loading from local directory

Tags: python

```
tydef prepare_data(batch_size):
(X_train, y_train)=load_data(TRAIN_DIR)
(X_test, y_test) = load_data(TEST_DIR)
X_all = np.concatenate([X_train, X_test])
y_all = np.concatenate([y_train, y_test])
X_all = X_all.astype(np.float32) / 255
X_all = X_all.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1) * 2. - 1.
y_all = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_all, 10)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_all, y_all))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(1024)
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(1)pe here
return dataset
```

This is the script to load the directory files using `TRAIN_DIR` variable.
But when I call the function `dataset = prepare_data(BATCH_SIZE)` it says "too many values to unpack (expected 2)".
Can you share your experiences?

Comment: Which line is giving you this error ? It could come from the first and second line where you want 2 output from `load data` and the function gives you only 1.

Comment: 1 def prepare_data(batch_size):
----> 2     (X_train, y_train)=load_data(TRAIN_DIR)
      3     (X_test, y_test) = load_data(TEST_DIR)
      4     X_all = np.concatenate([X_train, X_test])
      5     y_all = np.concatenate([y_train, y_test])

Comment: And where does your method `load_data` comes from ? What should it be returning ?

Comment: dataset = prepare_data(BATCH_SIZE)

gan = ConditionalGAN(
    discriminator=discriminator, generator=generator, 
    latent_dim=CODINGS_SIZE
)
gan.compile(
    d_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    g_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    loss_fn=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
)

Comment: here is the method

Comment: Does `load_data` comes from Keras, or did you write it?

Comment: from my google drive

Comment: Could you copy paste the `load_data` function that you use in the first line please?

Comment: let me show the three scripts continuously

Comment: def load_data(dir_path, img_size=(100,100)):
    """
    Load resized images as np.arrays to workspace
    """
    X = []
    y = []
    i = 0
    label = dict()

Comment: TRAIN_DIR = '/content/drive/MyDrive/computer_vision/main_dataset5/train/'
def prepare_data(batch_size):
    (X_train, y_train,X_test, y_test)=load_data(TRAIN_DIR)

Comment: dataset = prepare_data(BATCH_SIZE)

gan = ConditionalGAN(
    discriminator=discriminator, generator=generator, 
    latent_dim=CODINGS_SIZE
)

Comment: I don't see a `return` statement in your `load_data`. It could be the problem...

Comment: unable to post the whole

Comment: X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)
    print(f'{len(X)} images loaded from {dir_path} directory.')
    return X, y, label

Comment: this is the last return statement

Comment: def prepare_data(batch_size):
  X_train, y_train, lable = load_data(TRAIN_DIR)
 
  y_all = np.concatenate([y_train, y_test])
  
  X_all = X_all.astype(np.float32) / 255

Comment: still there is error

Comment: "setting an array element with a sequence" it says

Comment: If the error is different then this issue is solved. You should validate it and then ask another question. My advice would be to give all the element in the question (all the functions) and also the complete error trace to avoid all these comments.

Comment: Here is maybe an answer to the other error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence

Comment: mnist = datasets.MNIST(root='../data/', train=True, transform=transform, download=True) data_loader = DataLoader(dataset=mnist, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True)

Comment: how to change this file loader to my path to load from my device

Comment: Please, validate this answer and ask another question. This help other to find solution to the same problem as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, you have a function `load_data` like this:

```py
def load_data(dir_path, img_size=(100,100)):
    """ Load resized images as np.arrays to workspace """
    X = []
    y = []
    i = 0
    label = dict()
    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)
    print(f'{len(X)} images loaded from {dir_path} directory.')
    return X, y, label
```

which return two numpy arrays and one dictionary.

So I would change the beginning of the function `prepare_data` like so:

```py
def prepare_data(batch_size):
   X_train, y_train, label_train = load_data(TRAIN_DIR)
   X_test, y_test, label_test = load_data(TEST_DIR)
```

to match `load_data` signature.