# When using cvxpy, got TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cvxpy

I want to ask about an error "TypeError: Object arrays are not currently supported" when I use the python package "cvxpy" to solve a mixed integer programming problem.

The strange thing is, I can run the following codes without problems on my laptop and get the correct answer; but got the error when running the exact chunk of codes on a Linux server （the corresponding packages are installed on the server）

```
# Import packages.
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np


# Generate a random SDP.
n = 70
p = 20
np.random.seed(1)
A = np.random.rand(n, p)
np.random.seed(2)
C = np.random.rand(n, p)
np.random.seed(2)
Budget = np.random.rand(n, p)


# Define and solve the CVXPY problem.
# Create a symmetric matrix variable.
X = cp.Variable((n,p), boolean=True)
# The operator >> denotes matrix inequality.

constraints = [cp.trace(C @ X.T) >= 5]
constraints += [
   cp.sum(X[i]) == 1 for i in range(n)
]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(cp.trace(A @ X.T)),
                  constraints)
prob.solve(solver='GLPK_MI', verbose=True)


print("The optimal value is", prob.value)
print("A solution X is")
print(X.value)
```

When running it on the server, the error came out at line 20 compiling "constraints = [cp.trace(C @ X.T) >= 5]".

I have googled similar problems, for instance [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence), and most suggestions are about sub-array length mismatch. Clearly, I don't have the sub-array length mismatch issue and I am wondering what caused the error on server running.

Many thanks for any helps.

Comment: I suspect a difference in `numpy` versions.  Assuming the error is in `C @ X.T`, and one or the other is an object dtype array.  `matmul/@` is fastest when using float dtype arrays, where the job is done in compiled BLAS code.  Earlier versions couldn't handle `object` dtype arrays, but at some point the option was added.  It is performed in relatively slow python code.  Why you have object dtype array(s) may be worth exploring.  You shouldn't have them unintentionally.

Comment: You are right. I upgraded numpy to the latest version and the issue is solved. Thank you.