# Issue with the dtype of array generated by ImageDataGenerator in the tensorflow keras library

Tags: numpy, keras

I am currently using the Keras machine learning library to train a model for an image classification task. I have my data stored in a pandas DataFrame with the features being file paths to JPEG images and the labels being numpy float 32 arrays with shape (4, ).

When training my model, I come across this error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

I have traced this error to the ImageDataGenerator. When generating data using the `flow_from_dataframe` method, the generated features have dtype float32 but the generated labels have dtype object. When trying to convert the label array to float32, I get `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`.

Here is an example code for my generator:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255
)

train_df, val_df = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.1, random_state = 42)


train_gen = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe = train_df,
    x_col = "photo",
    y_col = 'label',
    target_size = (32, 32),
    class_mode = 'raw',
    batch_size = b_size
)

generated = train_gen.next()

features = generated[0]
labels = generated[1]

print(features.dtype) #prints float32
print(labels.dtype) #prints object
print(labels) #prints [array([1., 1., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
              #        array([1., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)
              #        array([1., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]

labels.astype(np.float32) #ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence) regarding `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence` but none of the given causes apply to my case.

I'm really confused as to why this error is occurring.

Could I have some advice?

Answer (score 1):

The labels variable has inhomogeneous structure (i.e. it is a list of numpy arrays, or an array with each row is a separate array).
So your code does not see labels as a numpy array with shape (N, 4), dtype float, but rather with shape (N, ), dtype object.

The reason for all this is that pandas gives the column with array cells inside the dtype object.
One trick is to read the content of that column cells as string formatting a list, then call eval() on it then construct a numpy array from the resulting list.

Comment: How would I do this if I am using flow_from_dataframe? I would need to do the reading and conversion inside the flow_from_dataframe method right? But I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Honestly I do not know how to do it with flow_from_dataframe (I will check it). But you can always right your own custom generator and implement any functionality inside it then return your batches with yield.