# Why do i get an error called "setting an array element with a sequence"?

Tags: python

im learning to code neutrons by video and got an error even tho my code equals the code of the tutorial, what am i doing wrong?

```
inputs = [[1, 2, 3, 2.5],
          [2.0, 5.0, -1.0, 2.0],
          [-1,5, 2.7, 3.3, -0.8]]
weights = [[0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0], 
           [0.5, -0.91, 0.26, -0.5], 
           [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87]]
biases = [2, 3, 0.5]

output = np.dot(inputs, np.array(weights).T) + biases
```

Comment: It is possible that you are just mixing types. See this previously answered question on [ValueErrors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674473/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence?rq=2) for a more detailed debugging approach.

Answer (score 3):

`-1,5` should be `-1.5` (in `inputs` array):

```py
inputs = [[1, 2, 3, 2.5], [2.0, 5.0, -1.0, 2.0], [-1.5, 2.7, 3.3, -0.8]]
weights = [[0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0], [0.5, -0.91, 0.26, -0.5], [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87]]
biases = [2, 3, 0.5]

output = np.dot(inputs, np.array(weights).T) + biases
print(output)
```

Prints:

```
[[ 4.8    1.21   2.385]
 [ 8.9   -1.81   0.2  ]
 [ 1.41   1.051  0.026]]
```